# Making my dialog look consistent across all versions of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have an Android activity themed as a Dialog, and while it looks great in vanilla Gingerbread, those with the latest gingerbread motoblur have this extra horrible looking black border around it which is the style of the dialog. How could I make the look consistent across most if not all varieties and versions of Android?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own custom theme you can make it look consistent across all versions. The problem with using the built in themes is this is defined differently for each device manufacturer. So you should be fine if you define your own theme.

Comment: is there a way to extract the vanilla gingerbread one to use?

Comment: You should be able to find it in your sdk folder. Location will be something like this C:\"Path to android sdk"\platforms\android-9\data\res\values\styles.xml. Just import that into your resources and any needed image files also found in the sdk folder to your project and you should be good.